# Error when trying to implement firebase with android-studio using the built in tool

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement firebase cloud messaging system in my android application to send out push notifications. However, when i try to use the incorporated tool in android studio to connect to firebase i get an error saying "Could not parse the Android Applications Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle issues and or resync".  When i checked the gradle file "build" in "import com.android.build.OutputFile" is highlighted red. When I hover over build "cannot resolve symbol build" pops up.

The application was build on react-native but the fcm system is done in android studio.

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.utechja"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-webview')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

lines 1-4 in app module(generated by react native) folder build.gradle file.

[image: Image of the error when connect firebase is clicked]

Comment: If you have a bug report or some observation that Firebase tooling isn't working the way you expect, please file that with Firebase.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: I think the problem was with android studio given that the tool won't work because the build.gradle file has an error

Comment: What would you expect it to do if there is an error?  Sounds like a non-starter.  Fix the error and try again.

Comment: I do not know how to fix the error android studio says the symbol is not recognized

Comment: @RumoneAnderson which symbol ?? try removing the `import com.android.build.OutputFile`.

Comment: I don't know the editor says exactly "cannot resolve symbol 'build' "

Comment: @MartinZeitler yeah I have tried removing it but then the compilation fails when i do

Comment: @RumoneAnderson also remove further usages of it; or comment them out... unless you'd add a proper error message, this isn't a question which could be reliably answered.